# Action hook to check and disallow placing an order in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, checkout, hook-woocommerce

I'm writing an extension for WooCommerce that will allow me to verify the customer's age before he can place an order. The age is verified by sending a specific request to an external API and depending on whether the result from API was successful or not, the Order should be successful or fail.

```
<?php
/**
 * LicenseScanner Integration
 *
 * Enables LicenseScanner integration.
 *
 * @class       WC_LicenseScanner
 * @extends     WC_Integration
 */
class WC_LicenseScanner extends WC_Integration {
    /**
     * Init and hook in the integration.
     *
     * @access public
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct() {
        $this->id                   = 'licensescanner';
        $this->method_title         = __( 'LicenseScanner', 'woocommerce' );
        $this->method_description   = __( 'LicenseScanner enables you to verify the age of the customer.', 'woocommerce' );
        // Load the settings.
        $this->init_form_fields();
        $this->init_settings();
        // Actions
        add_action( 'woocommerce_update_options_integration_licensescanner', array( $this, 'process_admin_options' ) );
        // Require phone number during the check-out
        add_filter( 'woocommerce_billing_fields', array($this, 'wc_mandatory_filter_phone'), 10, 1 );
        // Send age verification upon order
        add_action( 'woocommerce_pay_order_before_submit', array($this, 'request_age_verification'));
    }
    /**
     * Initialise Settings Form Fields
     *
     * @access public
     * @return void
     */
    function init_form_fields() {
        $this->form_fields = array(
            'enabled' => array(
                'title'             => __( 'License Bar Code Scanner URL:', 'woocommerce' ),
                'type'              => 'text',
                'description'       => __( 'Enter the License Bar Code Scanner URL that the notification should be sent to once the user attempts to check out', 'woocommerce' ),
                'desc_tip'          => true,
                'default'           => get_option('woocommerce_licensescanner') ? get_option('woocommerce_licensescanner') : ''
            )
        );
    }

    function wc_mandatory_filter_phone( $address_fields ) {
        $address_fields['billing_phone']['required'] = true;
        return $address_fields;
    }

    function request_age_verification() {
        throw new Exception('The age verification failed');
    }
}
```

So apparently throwing an exception is not good enough to fail the order... or perhaps I'm hooked to a wrong action?
I could somehow try to disable the order button with JS, but that is not good enough if a potential attacker just enables it in his browser or forges a request to the backend

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using `woocommerce_pay_order_before_submit`, you should try to hook in dedicated **`woocommerce_checkout_process`** action hook, so in your code:

```
// Send age verification upon order
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_process', array( $this, 'request_age_verification' ) );
```

It should work with it…

This hooke is located in [`WC_Checkout` `process_checkout()` method](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/source-class-WC_Checkout.html#959)

Comment: their documentation really sucks in that sense. Thanks! Works like a charm!

Comment: @KamilJanowski Hopefully there is StackOverFlow :) … Is just a question to be used to and of code logic. For woocommerce checkout submit event, the right hook to make custom checks and return an error is `'woocommerce_checkout_process'`…